# Get the scene that MonoBehaviour belongs to (multi-scene setup)

Tags: unity

Is there a way to get the scene that a MonoBehaviour component belongs to? The MonoBehaviour is part of a setup with several additivly loaded scenes. What I'm looking for is not the currently active scene but an additionally loaded one.

Comment: You mean [gameObject.scene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-scene.html)?

Comment: Thanks, I was looking everywhere... except at the most obvious place :)